# How do vectors accurately predict the outcomes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors

In the beginning of every physics class in school, we learn vectors.
And, then learn their algebra.
Then start using them, as we do with a lot other math branches, in physics.

We say that the force is a vector because:
It is dependent on displacement, and derived from it, multiplying scalars and scalars; and by laws of vectors, force, thus becomes a vector, because displacement is by definition a vector and force is derived from it.

But why do two (or more) forces acting on a body follow laws of vectors. I ask this because, force is force and why does it have to follow the law of triangle vector addition or parallelogram or polygon, etc.

Comment: Actually, the opposite is true. Historically, people did not consider displacements as a vector. The law of triangle vector addition was first derived from forces behaving that way, and then we realised that vectors are everywhere and displacements behaved that way too.

Comment: I understand...

Comment: TLDR, it's not by accident. Modelling displacement and velocity and acceleration and force and momentum is the purpose for which vectors were _invented._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows because displacement is a vector. Consequently velocity, being the difference of displacements divided by the scalar  "time", obeys the vector addition rule. Then *acceleration*, being the difference of  vector velocities divided by time, is  also a  vector. Finally *force*, being acceleration multiplied by the scalar "mass" also  obeys the vector addition rule.

Comment: So the fact that displacement is a vector and obeys laws of vectors, makes force follow the same laws, because it is derived from it. And the fact that displacement follows laws of vectors, is more digestible to me.I understand. Thank you

Comment: @naturallyinconsistent 's comment is also quite true!  Experiment came first and then the math logic later.

Comment: I like this argument too.